# Set PDF Options in Julia Markdown

Tags: pdf, julia, latex, markdown

I have a Julia Markdown file (`jmd`).

````
---
title: My Title
output: pdf_document
---

```julia echo=false
6+4
```
````

How can I transport information to LaTex? For example I would like to set the paper orientation to `landscape` or decrease the font size or similar. I thought be there must be something similar to `Rmarkdown`, something like

```
---
title: My title
output: 
  pdf_document:
    toc: true
    number_sections: true
documentclass: article
classoption: landscape, a3paper
---
```

But it does not work in `jmd` files. Anyone a clever idea?

Answer (score 3):

## Setting Configurations on Two Fronts

### Weave Options

[`weave_options`](http://weavejl.mpastell.com/stable/header/#Configuration-Options) can be specified in a Julia Markdown Document's front matter. These are options that might otherwise be passed to the `weave` function as keyword arguments (configuration in front matter takes precedence over function call options). E.g., one can define the `doctype` and `highlight` options. Optionally, one may also define a custom latex [`template`](http://weavejl.mpastell.com/stable/publish/#Templates). The following front matter would set these options.

```markdown
---
title: My Title
author: Me
date: March 21, 2022
weave_options:
    doctype: pandoc2pdf
    highlight: pygments
    template: relative/path/to/custom.tpl
---
```

### Pandoc Options

Assuming that your working with `doctype: pandoc2pdf` or `doctype: pandoc2html` then you can also set Pandoc options by passing them as a vector of strings to the `pandoc_options` keyword argument of the `weave` function. E.g., for a table of contents and numbered sections one could run the following.

```sh
weave("test.jmd", pandoc_options=["--toc", "-N"])
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for contributing. Where can I find the `pandoc` options that I can possibly set? E.g. I am looking for the paper orientation - but is there a complete list somewhere?

Comment: The Pandoc User Guide has a [`--variable`](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#general-writer-options) option. This could be used to set the orientation with the following command: `weave("test.jmd", pandoc_options=["--variable geometry:landscape"])` or `weave("test.jmd", pandoc_options=["-V geometry:landscape"])`.

Comment: This does not seem to work, but `pandoc.exe test.jmd -V geometry:landscape -f markdown -o test.pdf` will do the trick. Should probably open an issue with the package.